# Location extends to another UTM coordinate zone

Tags: coordinate-system, mapping, utm

I was working on a project that's located in an area in my state. In that area, it cuts between UTM coordinate system zones 31 and 32. What problems will I encounter in representing the map, and how can I attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Since you obviously can't use both UTM zones, you need to choose one, or a different projection that covers the same area. Unfortunately, that's a choice *you* need to make, since any answer we could give would be *opinion-based*.

Comment: This question does not necessarily seek an opinion-based answer -- no more than 90% of all other questions. So let's not scare off another new user so hastily. The question may need more detail before a more detailed answer can be provided, though. Until then, Vince's brief answer should do: "Since you obviously can't use both UTM zones, you need to choose one, or a different projection that covers the same area."

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

If overlapping is a problem or not depends on two factors:

1. How much the overlap is.
2. What you intend to do (what precision and accuracy you need).

To solve the problem, there also two solutions as well:

1. Split up your map to smaller ones that are completely within the same UTM zone .
2. Look for another projection - one that covers the whole extent of your area of interest.

**Longer answer**

The problem you'll encounter when extending your map over the extent of your UTM zone is higher distortion. **Any** projection distorts earth's surface and UTM zones are designed to minimize the distortion. See this statement:

> Within these zones the UTM projection has very little distortion. UTM
> coordinates can be extended into a neighboring zone for seamless
> operations, but the farther away from the 6 degree zone you move, the
> greater the distortion.

[UTM projection, United States Naval Academy](https://www.usna.edu/Users/oceano/pguth/md_help/html/cartography/utm.htm)

This site here explains UTM projections very clearly:

[GIS Geography: How Universal Transverse Mercator (UTM) Works](https://gisgeography.com/utm-universal-transverse-mercator-projection/)

> [...] scale is constant north-south along the Meridians. But scale
> varies east-west along parallels. The two small circles are 180
> kilometers east and west of the central Meridian at the Equator. The
> small circles have a scale factor of 1, meaning a distance of 100
> meters in the ellipsoid would be the same on the map projection. The
> centerline of a UTM grid zone has a scale factor of 0.9996. This means
> that a distance of 100 meters on an ellipsoid would be 99.96 meters on
> a map.

And:

> The UTM projection minimizes distortion within that zone. So this
> means that when you want to show features in several UTM zone, it
> starts becoming a poor choice of map projection. Distortion is small
> near the central meridian, and as you move away it worsens. So this
> makes it most fitting for narrow regions and not well-suited for world
> maps.

> Universal Transverse Mercator was really meant to map features in
> **one UTM zone at a time** [bold in original]. (...) The Universal Transverse Mercator is horrible for small-scale (less-detailed) maps
> like world atlases and perfect for mapping narrow regions.

See also See also Wikipedia on [Universal Transverse Mercator coordinate system: Overlapping grids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#Overlapping_grids):

> Around the boundaries of large scale maps (1:100,000 or larger)
> coordinates for both adjoining UTM zones are usually printed within a
> minimum distance of 40 km on either side of a zone boundary. Ideally,
> the coordinates of each position should be measured on the grid for
> the zone in which they are located, but because the scale factor is
> still relatively small near zone boundaries, it is possible to overlap
> measurements into an adjoining zone for some distance when necessary.

So the question is rather how much more the distortion gets outside of the extent of the respective UTM zone. Of corse, the more you get away from it, the bigger the distortion gets. So for just tiny overlapping with the neighboring zone, that might not be a problem - but it depends on what you want to achieve.

Edit by user @John Uko:

> There is a conceptual error in the contents of the website that is
> quoted in this answer, which I am correcting :
>
> The distortion is small near the central meridian and it(distortion)
> actually decreases as we move towards the standard circle and beyond
> the standard circle, the distortion starts to worsen again.